# How to select first column with categorical or factor datatype and draw pairplot in R using GGally?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I am using below code to plot `Pairplot` based on categorical data type. However, I was wondering if there is library which basically  search for column with categorical or factor datatype and then plot the pairplot based on 1st column containing datatype category or factor ? In below code we already know "Species" column is categorical datatype. However, let's say If I have dataframe  containing multiple columns with categorical or factor datatype. Below is example data and I want to plot `Pairplot` based on location column.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
ggpairs(iris,aes(colour = Species))
```

**dput of the dataset**

```
structure(list(location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Afghanistan", 
"Africa", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", 
"Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Asia", 
"Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
"Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", 
"Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bonaire Sint Eustatius and Saba", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Botswana", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", 
"Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", 
"Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", 
"Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Cook Islands", 
"Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Curacao", 
"Cyprus", "Czechia", "Democratic Republic of Congo", "Denmark", 
"Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", 
"El Salvador", "England", "Equatorial Guinea", "Estonia", "Eswatini", 
"Ethiopia", "Europe", "European Union", "Faeroe Islands", "Falkland Islands", 
"Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Polynesia", "Gabon", "Gambia", 
"Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", 
"Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Guyana", "Haiti", "High income", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", 
"Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", 
"Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", 
"Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kosovo", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", 
"Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", 
"Lithuania", "Low income", "Lower middle income", "Luxembourg", 
"Macao", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", 
"Malta", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Moldova", "Monaco", 
"Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", 
"Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Caledonia", 
"New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "North America", 
"North Macedonia", "Northern Cyprus", "Northern Ireland", "Norway", 
"Oceania", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", 
"Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", 
"Qatar", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Helena", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", 
"Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", 
"Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Scotland", "Senegal", 
"Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Sint Maarten (Dutch part)", 
"Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", 
"South America", "South Korea", "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", 
"Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Timor", "Togo", "Tokelau", 
"Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", 
"Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Kingdom", "United States", "Upper middle income", "Uruguay", 
"Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Wales", "Wallis and Futuna", 
"World", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), iso_code = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "AIA", "ALB", 
"AND", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", "ATG", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BDI", 
"BEL", "BEN", "BES", "BFA", "BGD", "BGR", "BHR", "BHS", "BIH", 
"BLR", "BLZ", "BMU", "BOL", "BRA", "BRB", "BRN", "BTN", "BWA", 
"CAF", "CAN", "CHE", "CHL", "CHN", "CIV", "CMR", "COD", "COG", 
"COK", "COL", "COM", "CPV", "CRI", "CUB", "CUW", "CYM", "CYP", 
"CZE", "DEU", "DJI", "DMA", "DNK", "DOM", "DZA", "ECU", "EGY", 
"ESP", "EST", "ETH", "FIN", "FJI", "FLK", "FRA", "FRO", "GAB", 
"GBR", "GEO", "GGY", "GHA", "GIB", "GIN", "GMB", "GNB", "GNQ", 
"GRC", "GRD", "GRL", "GTM", "GUY", "HKG", "HND", "HRV", "HTI", 
"HUN", "IDN", "IMN", "IND", "IRL", "IRN", "IRQ", "ISL", "ISR", 
"ITA", "JAM", "JEY", "JOR", "JPN", "KAZ", "KEN", "KGZ", "KHM", 
"KIR", "KNA", "KOR", "KWT", "LAO", "LBN", "LBR", "LBY", "LCA", 
"LIE", "LKA", "LSO", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MAC", "MAR", "MCO", 
"MDA", "MDG", "MDV", "MEX", "MKD", "MLI", "MLT", "MMR", "MNE", 
"MNG", "MOZ", "MRT", "MSR", "MUS", "MWI", "MYS", "NAM", "NCL", 
"NER", "NGA", "NIC", "NIU", "NLD", "NOR", "NPL", "NRU", "NZL", 
"OMN", "OWID_AFR", "OWID_ASI", "OWID_CYN", "OWID_ENG", "OWID_EUN", 
"OWID_EUR", "OWID_HIC", "OWID_KOS", "OWID_LIC", "OWID_LMC", "OWID_NAM", 
"OWID_NIR", "OWID_OCE", "OWID_SAM", "OWID_SCT", "OWID_UMC", "OWID_WLS", 
"OWID_WRL", "PAK", "PAN", "PCN", "PER", "PHL", "PNG", "POL", 
"PRT", "PRY", "PSE", "PYF", "QAT", "ROU", "RUS", "RWA", "SAU", 
"SDN", "SEN", "SGP", "SHN", "SLB", "SLE", "SLV", "SMR", "SOM", 
"SRB", "SSD", "STP", "SUR", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE", "SWZ", "SXM", 
"SYC", "SYR", "TCA", "TCD", "TGO", "THA", "TJK", "TKL", "TKM", 
"TLS", "TON", "TTO", "TUN", "TUR", "TUV", "TWN", "TZA", "UGA", 
"UKR", "URY", "USA", "UZB", "VCT", "VEN", "VGB", "VNM", "VUT", 
"WLF", "WSM", "YEM", "ZAF", "ZMB", "ZWE"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(84:89, .Label = c("2020-12-01", "2020-12-02", 
    "2020-12-03", "2020-12-04", "2020-12-05", "2020-12-06", "2020-12-07", 
    "2020-12-08", "2020-12-09", "2020-12-10", "2020-12-11", "2020-12-12", 
    "2020-12-13", "2020-12-14", "2020-12-15", "2020-12-16", "2020-12-17", 
    "2020-12-18", "2020-12-19", "2020-12-20", "2020-12-21", "2020-12-22", 
    "2020-12-23", "2020-12-24", "2020-12-25", "2020-12-26", "2020-12-27", 
    "2020-12-28", "2020-12-29", "2020-12-30", "2020-12-31", "2021-01-01", 
    "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06", 
    "2021-01-07", "2021-01-08", "2021-01-09", "2021-01-10", "2021-01-11", 
    "2021-01-12", "2021-01-13", "2021-01-14", "2021-01-15", "2021-01-16", 
    "2021-01-17", "2021-01-18", "2021-01-19", "2021-01-20", "2021-01-21", 
    "2021-01-22", "2021-01-23", "2021-01-24", "2021-01-25", "2021-01-26", 
    "2021-01-27", "2021-01-28", "2021-01-29", "2021-01-30", "2021-01-31", 
    "2021-02-01", "2021-02-02", "2021-02-03", "2021-02-04", "2021-02-05", 
    "2021-02-06", "2021-02-07", "2021-02-08", "2021-02-09", "2021-02-10", 
    "2021-02-11", "2021-02-12", "2021-02-13", "2021-02-14", "2021-02-15", 
    "2021-02-16", "2021-02-17", "2021-02-18", "2021-02-19", "2021-02-20", 
    "2021-02-21", "2021-02-22", "2021-02-23", "2021-02-24", "2021-02-25", 
    "2021-02-26", "2021-02-27", "2021-02-28", "2021-03-01", "2021-03-02", 
    "2021-03-03", "2021-03-04", "2021-03-05", "2021-03-06", "2021-03-07", 
    "2021-03-08", "2021-03-09", "2021-03-10", "2021-03-11", "2021-03-12", 
    "2021-03-13", "2021-03-14", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-16", "2021-03-17", 
    "2021-03-18", "2021-03-19", "2021-03-20", "2021-03-21", "2021-03-22", 
    "2021-03-23", "2021-03-24", "2021-03-25", "2021-03-26", "2021-03-27", 
    "2021-03-28", "2021-03-29", "2021-03-30", "2021-03-31", "2021-04-01", 
    "2021-04-02", "2021-04-03", "2021-04-04", "2021-04-05", "2021-04-06", 
    "2021-04-07", "2021-04-08", "2021-04-09", "2021-04-10", "2021-04-11", 
    "2021-04-12", "2021-04-13", "2021-04-14", "2021-04-15", "2021-04-16", 
    "2021-04-17", "2021-04-18", "2021-04-19", "2021-04-20", "2021-04-21", 
    "2021-04-22", "2021-04-23", "2021-04-24", "2021-04-25", "2021-04-26", 
    "2021-04-27", "2021-04-28", "2021-04-29", "2021-04-30", "2021-05-01", 
    "2021-05-02", "2021-05-03", "2021-05-04", "2021-05-05", "2021-05-06", 
    "2021-05-07", "2021-05-08", "2021-05-09", "2021-05-10", "2021-05-11", 
    "2021-05-12", "2021-05-13", "2021-05-14", "2021-05-15", "2021-05-16", 
    "2021-05-17", "2021-05-18", "2021-05-19", "2021-05-20", "2021-05-21", 
    "2021-05-22", "2021-05-23", "2021-05-24", "2021-05-25", "2021-05-26", 
    "2021-05-27", "2021-05-28", "2021-05-29", "2021-05-30", "2021-05-31", 
    "2021-06-01", "2021-06-02", "2021-06-03", "2021-06-04", "2021-06-05", 
    "2021-06-06", "2021-06-07", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-10", 
    "2021-06-11", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-13", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-15", 
    "2021-06-16", "2021-06-17", "2021-06-18", "2021-06-19", "2021-06-20", 
    "2021-06-21", "2021-06-22", "2021-06-23", "2021-06-24", "2021-06-25", 
    "2021-06-26", "2021-06-27", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-29", "2021-06-30", 
    "2021-07-01", "2021-07-02", "2021-07-03", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05", 
    "2021-07-06", "2021-07-07", "2021-07-08", "2021-07-09", "2021-07-10", 
    "2021-07-11", "2021-07-12", "2021-07-13", "2021-07-14", "2021-07-15", 
    "2021-07-16", "2021-07-17", "2021-07-18", "2021-07-19", "2021-07-20", 
    "2021-07-21", "2021-07-22", "2021-07-23", "2021-07-24", "2021-07-25", 
    "2021-07-26", "2021-07-27", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-29", "2021-07-30", 
    "2021-07-31", "2021-08-01", "2021-08-02", "2021-08-03", "2021-08-04", 
    "2021-08-05", "2021-08-06", "2021-08-07", "2021-08-08", "2021-08-09", 
    "2021-08-10", "2021-08-11", "2021-08-12", "2021-08-13", "2021-08-14", 
    "2021-08-15", "2021-08-16", "2021-08-17", "2021-08-18", "2021-08-19", 
    "2021-08-20", "2021-08-21", "2021-08-22", "2021-08-23", "2021-08-24", 
    "2021-08-25", "2021-08-26", "2021-08-27", "2021-08-28", "2021-08-29", 
    "2021-08-30", "2021-08-31", "2021-09-01", "2021-09-02", "2021-09-03", 
    "2021-09-04", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-08", 
    "2021-09-09", "2021-09-10", "2021-09-11", "2021-09-12", "2021-09-13", 
    "2021-09-14", "2021-09-15", "2021-09-16", "2021-09-17", "2021-09-18", 
    "2021-09-19", "2021-09-20", "2021-09-21", "2021-09-22", "2021-09-23", 
    "2021-09-24", "2021-09-25", "2021-09-26", "2021-09-27", "2021-09-28", 
    "2021-09-29", "2021-09-30", "2021-10-01", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-03", 
    "2021-10-04", "2021-10-05", "2021-10-06", "2021-10-07", "2021-10-08", 
    "2021-10-09", "2021-10-10", "2021-10-11", "2021-10-12", "2021-10-13", 
    "2021-10-14", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-16", "2021-10-17", "2021-10-18", 
    "2021-10-19", "2021-10-20", "2021-10-21", "2021-10-22", "2021-10-23", 
    "2021-10-24", "2021-10-25", "2021-10-26", "2021-10-27", "2021-10-28", 
    "2021-10-29", "2021-10-30", "2021-10-31", "2021-11-01", "2021-11-02", 
    "2021-11-03", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-06", "2021-11-07", 
    "2021-11-08", "2021-11-09", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-11", "2021-11-12", 
    "2021-11-13", "2021-11-14", "2021-11-15", "2021-11-16", "2021-11-17", 
    "2021-11-18", "2021-11-19", "2021-11-20", "2021-11-21", "2021-11-22", 
    "2021-11-23", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-25", "2021-11-26", "2021-11-27", 
    "2021-11-28", "2021-11-29", "2021-11-30", "2021-12-01", "2021-12-02", 
    "2021-12-03", "2021-12-04", "2021-12-05", "2021-12-06", "2021-12-07", 
    "2021-12-08", "2021-12-09", "2021-12-10", "2021-12-11", "2021-12-12", 
    "2021-12-13", "2021-12-14", "2021-12-15", "2021-12-16", "2021-12-17", 
    "2021-12-18", "2021-12-19", "2021-12-20", "2021-12-21", "2021-12-22", 
    "2021-12-23", "2021-12-24", "2021-12-25", "2021-12-26", "2021-12-27", 
    "2021-12-28", "2021-12-29", "2021-12-30", "2021-12-31", "2022-01-01", 
    "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", 
    "2022-01-07", "2022-01-08"), class = "factor"), total_vaccinations = c(0, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), people_vaccinated = c(0, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), people_fully_vaccinated = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), total_boosters = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), daily_vaccinations_raw = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), daily_vaccinations = c(NA, 
    1367L, 1367L, 1367L, 1367L, 1367L), total_vaccinations_per_hundred = c(0, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), people_vaccinated_per_hundred = c(0, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), total_boosters_per_hundred = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), daily_vaccinations_per_million = c(NA, 
    34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L), daily_people_vaccinated = c(NA, 
    1367L, 1367L, 1367L, 1367L, 1367L), daily_people_vaccinated_per_hundred = c(NA, 
    0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000007b01ef0>)
```

Comment: Would something like this help? `ggpairs(iris,aes(colour = iris[,min(which(sapply(iris,is.factor)))]))`. I wasn't able to apply this to `location` in the data you provided because ggpairs doesn't recommend working with more than 15 levels (there are 235 locations)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code does what you're looking for.

This code doesn't work with the dataset you included as there are too many invalid numbers/entries

```
library(tidyverse)

#get list of column types
class_list<- sapply(df, class) 

#get only categorical columns (assuming character is categorical)
categorical_column_names<-class_list[class_list=="character" | class_list=="factor"]

#relevel factors to reduce number of unused factor levels to get below the max 15 allowed by ggpairs, 
df_simpler_factors<- sapply(df, 
                            function(x) if(class(x)=="factor"){  
                              as.character(x) %>% fct_relevel
                              } else { 
                                x
                              }
) %>% data.frame

ggpairs(df_simpler_factors ,
#pick the first column as the main category
aes(colour = categorical_column_names[1])
)
```

Comment: @Roger-123..I am getting an error that says "Error in ggpairs(df_simpler_factors, aes(colour = categorical_column_names[1])) : 
  object 'df_simpler_factors' not found"

Comment: @biggboss2019 did you run all the code I posted? What happens when you run the code to create the object `df_simpler_factors`? you may need to adjust the code and replace `df` with the actual name of your data.frame.

Comment: @Roger-123..Yes, I tried running entire code and replace the data frame with iris data set to give it a try but received an error that says "Error in fct_relevel(.) : could not find function "fct_relevel". I am using Tidyverse 1.3.1

Comment: @biggboss2019 strange. You may have to install and load the library `forcats`. It's part of the tidyverse, so it should have loaded when you loaded the tidyverse library. When you load the tidyverse for the first time, what packages does it list under "-- Attaching packages -----"?

Comment: @Roger-123..loading forcats resolved the issue. However, I don't see 3 different color for 3 different factors in Iris dataset. I only see correlation value and same correlation value for factor